# Cascading dropdowns are returning undefined in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I know this question is on a lot of others here. But here is my issue regarding the matter.

My Json Call in homecontroller:

```cs
public JsonResult GetBrand(int id)
{
    List<String> resultdata = new List<String>();

    //get some data via sql query
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconn))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                resultdata.Add(reader.GetString(0));
            }
        }
    }

    return Json(resultdata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My 2nd Dropdown's code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Brand", new SelectList(string.Empty, "", ""), "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

I also tried:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Brand", new SelectList(string.Empty, "div_id ", "material_name "), "Please select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

And my script:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#category").change(function () {
        $.get("GetBrand", { id: $("#category").val() }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#Brand").empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, row) {
                console.log(row);
                $("#Brand").append("<option value='" + row.div_id + "'>" + row.material_name + "</option>")
            });
        });
    })
});
```

On Chrome's F12 console, I can see this actual list of data I want returned in the dropdown and it is correct (via console.log(row);).
However, in the dropdown itself, it shows undefined.

Does anyone have any suggestions to what I am missing?

Comment: What values are you getting when you print the `row` on console?

Comment: I get the brand names ex: brand 1, brand 2 etc. Exactly how it should display on the dropdown.

Comment: If I do this in the Json Call: return Json(new SelectList(resultdata, "div_id", "material_name"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); I get an error: Internal Server Error(500)

Comment: So I think my Json call is correct, there is something wrong either the script or the Dropdown itself???

Comment: In  `$.get("GetBrand", .... )` you need to write like this:  `$.get("/Home/GetBrand" ,...)`. It is not getting the path of controllers action method, hence the error. Also the path is case sensitive. So make sure that you write the Controllers name exactly what you have given while creating your controller.

Comment: I added your suggestion and it still does the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my fix for anyone also missing something so simple:

```
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    items.Add(new SelectListItem
                    {                           
                        
                        Value = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(reader["div_id"])),
                        Text = reader["material_name"].ToString()
                    });
                }
```

Now it returns values.